# Getting null pointer exception using ExtentReport

Tags: java, testng

I have 3 class . Test1,Test2 and Base class. Test1 and Test2 extends Base class. When i am executing both classes using TestNg xml it fails @BeforeClass with null pointer exception. Report of test1 is getting generated. Also without extent report its working fine. Please help me

====================================Base Class==============================

```
public class Base
{
public ExtentReports reports;
public ExtentTest logger;
  @BeforeClass

  public void startBrowser() 
  {
      String name= LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMYY_HHmmss"));
      logger = reports.createTest("Test1"+name);
      System.out.println("Started Test1");

}

  @BeforeSuite
  public void initialSetup()
  {
      String name= LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMYY_HHmmss"));
      ExtentHtmlReporter extent = new ExtentHtmlReporter(new File("./Reports/"+name+".html"));
      reports = new ExtentReports();
      reports.attachReporter(extent); 
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void end()
  {
      reports.flush();
  }

}
```

===========================Test1 class=====================

```
public class Test1 extends Base{
  @Test
  public void TestCase() 
  {

      logger.info("Test1");
  }
}
```

====================Test2 class=============================

```
public class Test2 extends Base{
  @Test
  public void f() 
  {
      System.out.println("Started Test2");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your test code.
You have initialised the data member `reports` in a `@BeforeSuite` annotated method.

This gets executed only once per `<suite>` tag.
Since both your classes are extending from the same base class, the `initialSetup()` method will get executed only once (for e.g., Test1.java).

That is why when your `@BeforeClass` annotated `startBrowser()` attempts at accessing `reports.createTest("Test1"+name);` for `Test2` you hit a NullPointerException.

You need to change this by moving your `initialSetup()` invocation from within a `@BeforeClass` method.